# What medical supplies should I take with me on a walking / biking trip in New Zealand?

Tags: health, nature-and-wildlife, hiking, new-zealand

I plan on going to New Zealand for the summer months. I hope to hike a lot there, but also use a bike for longer distances.
I assume I will be on my own in the nature for 2-3 days, then in an inhabited area for a while to re-supply and enjoy things the city/town has to offer, and then back to the nature.

What sort of medical supplies should I bring with me on such a trip? 
I assume some bandages and some disinfectant in the case of a light cut, but I'm also thinking of stuff like [Norit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activated_carbon).

Would anyone with some experience on this mode of travel know what a first-aid kit should contain?

Comment: Yes it applies to first world people only, third world people do not need medical supplies, we have abilities to self-heal within minutes! we even can grow amputated limbs.

Comment: Best medical supply you can have is a satellite phone. :)

Comment: Thank you @HaLaBi for thinking with me, I heard the medicine men in third world countries were pretty good... I added that line because I assumed that cities in first world countries have easier access to certain medicines than third world countries. Meaning that I can resupply my first aid kit easier. Can I conclude from your comment that my assumption is not correct? Is access to medicine equal in first and third world countries?

Comment: @Karlson I thought of that, but who would I call with it? The emergency services? Can they track my phone down with reasonable precision? I have seen that it works in the movies, but I have no clue how this works in real life. Feel free to elaborate your comment and make an answer out of it.

Comment: @BartArondson Most if not all modern cell phones are equipped with GPS chips.  Only stand to reason that satellite phones will be as well.

Comment: @BartArondson it was more like a bad joke :)

Comment: you might be interested in http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/603/what-essential-items-should-go-in-a-small-first-aid-kit and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13989/what-first-aid-material-and-medicines-are-absolutely-essential-when-traveling/13999#13999

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, I would think that population density and climate are at least as important as perceived level of development.

Comment: @Annoyed Yes, I agree. I just removed the last sentence to make the question NZ specific. Apparently my assumption was not correct.

Comment: @BartArondson I know you edited it, but I could add that sometimes it's easier to get some medicines in some countries (where drugstores don't require a prescription), if you know something about the meds you need.

Comment: @BartArondson adjusted heading to make it more obvious in the title that it's NZ, as it would differ for other countries. Hope that's ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many areas of New Zealand wilderness are very far off the beaten track.  You may find you are out of cellphone coverage for several days at a time.  Smart people rent personal locator beacons if they plan to go tramping alone.  The water in the mountains is pretty safe to drink, but if the river drains farmland then you would need some kind of filtration system.  Treatment for blisters is important, as is insect repellent.  Most places have a local formulation that they swear by.  The weather in NZ is VERY changeable, and it's important to carry lots of layers, especially wool or polyprop.  If you do have an accident, you'll be pleased to know that the ACC (Accident Compensation Corporation) covers tourist's medical expenses and there are no maximums or co-pays.  But you'll still need insurance for illnesses.

That's more info than you asked for, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Seconding sandfly repellant (I live in the South Island and sandflies are a real pain), some anti-histamines are a good idea as wasps are common in some places in the summer, and DON'T just drink any stream water, even in the mountains as Giardia (aka beaver fever) is quite common especially in the North Island (I've always used iodine pills or similar to treat my water).

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to take some sandflies repellent
I think that Johnson's OFF (the orange one)  is best